# Can't ping or remote desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ping, remote

I've setup a win7 laptop and joined a company domain, now I'm unable to ping or remote into the machine.

Could someone provide me with some troubleshooting tips please?

Comment: Are you an administrator for the domain in question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that the windows firewall got turned on by a group policy that was applied following the AD join process.

You'll need to disable that policy do the machine or amend the firewall rules to allow your desired traffic.

Answer (score 1):

When you join a domain, your computer changes from the Home/Work/Public network location that you had previously selected to the Domain location. There are different firewall profiles with different rules for each of these locations. If you've disabled or made specific firewall rules to allow access to these services, you might not have made the same configurations on the Domain profile of the firewall.

Alternatively, there could be a GPO enforcing certain firewall settings. You can check this with either `gpresult` or `rsop.msc`