# Can't ping or remote desktop on Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, ping, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t ping or remote desktop?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453042/cant-ping-or-remote-desktop)

I've setup a win7 laptop and joined a company domain, I'm unable to ping or remote into the machine.

I've tried removing it from the domain and I still have the same problem...

Could someone provide me with some troubleshooting tips please?

Comment: IP address? Windows Firewall? Etc., etc. Can you give us some details on the configuration and what happens or what messages you get when trying to ping or connect to it?

Comment: Why did you post this question a second time under a new username? I already answered your old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ICMP (or file sharing) and remote desktop from within the Windows 7 firewall.  Also, since you are joining a domain, this may be controlled by group policy.